# How can I port commands.getoutput calls to Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, standard-library

commands.getoutput() was deprecated AFAIR in current Python 2.x and removed in Py3k.

How does one obtain similar information in clean Python 3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The verbatim equivalent is [`subprocess.getoutput`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getoutput). However, you virtually always want to throw an exception if the command fails and therefore use [**`subprocess.check_output`**](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).